# How to pass raw mp3 from recyclerview item to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, media-player

In my Android app I have a recyclerview which contains a list of items. In recyclerview activity each item has one textview and another activity has two textview and one audio play button. But audio not playing. How can I set setOnClickListener and play audio mp3 usung MediaPlayer. Here is my code-

NameModel.java

```
public class NameModel {

    private String name,meaning;
    private int audio;

    public NameModel(String name, String meaning, int audio) {

        this.name= name;
        this.meaning= meaning;
        this.audio= audio;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getMeaning() {
        return meaning;
    }

    public void setMeaning(String meaning) {
        this.meaning= meaning;
    }

    public int getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(int audio) {
        this.audio = audio;
    }
}
```

NameAdapter.java

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position=getAdapterPosition();
                    NameModel nameModel=nameItemList.get(position);

                    Intent intent=new Intent(context, NameDetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("NAME",nameModel.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("MEANING",nameModel.getMeaning());
                    intent.putExtra("AUDIO", nameModel.getAudio());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private List<NameModel> nameModelList;
    private NameAdapter nameAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView  = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);
        nameModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        nameAdapter = new NameAdapter(this,nameModelList);

        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration=new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        nameModelList.add(new NameModel("Mahmud", "The praised one", R.raw.mahmud));
        nameModelList.add(new NameModel("Maaz", "Brave Man", R.raw.maaz));
    }
}
```

NameDetailsActivity.java

```
public class NameDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    NameModel nameModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_name);

        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
        String meaning = getIntent().getStringExtra("MEANING");
        int audio = getIntent().getIntExtra("AUDIO",0);

        TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView meaningText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMeaning);
        Button playbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);

        nameText.setText(name);
        meaningText.setText(meaning);

        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,audio);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }

        });
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're doing `getIntent().getStringExtra("AUDIO");` which is not right in this case. 
You set int value in your `intent.putExtra("AUDIO", nameModel.getAudio());` so you have to get int value back using `int audio = getIntent().getIntExtra("AUDIO");`. Hope it will help you.

Also I've noticed 1 thing. In your NameDetailsActivity where do you initialize your context and your NameModel class? Actually I don't know why you need `NameModel` class in `NameDetailsActivity`, but anyway... If you will pass that context to mediaplayer without initialization, you will get nullPointerException. And you get exception like `Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.tahmid.name.models.NameModel.getAudioFile()'`. That's because your `NameModel` class in `NameDetailsActivity` is null.

You have to do 2 things.
If you need `NameModel` class in `NameDetailsActivity`, you have to create an empty constructor in `NameModel` class. You can find it in my answer below. And you have to initialize context and nameModel in `NameDetailsActivity`.

So try this code.

First of all in your `NameModel` create an empty constructor.

```
public class NameModel {

private String name,meaning;
private int audio;

public NameModel() {}

public NameModel(String name, String meaning, int audio) {

    this.name= name;
    this.meaning= meaning;
    this.audio= audio;
}

// The same code...
```

And your `NameDetailsActivity` you can do this.

```
public class NameDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context;
NameModel nameModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_name);

    context = getContext();
    nameModel = new NameModel();

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("NAME");
    String meaning = getIntent().getStringExtra("MEANING");
    int audio = getIntent().getIntExtra("AUDIO",0);

    TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView meaningText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMeaning);
    Button playbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);

    nameText.setText(name);
    meaningText.setText(meaning);

    playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,audio);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: thanks @Hayk Mkrtchyan, after replacing with int audio = getIntent().getIntExtra("AUDIO");. same problem and i checked crashlytics report. its showing- 
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.tahmid.name.models.NameModel.getAudioFile()' on a null object reference. pls help me.

Comment: Also give +1 to my answer.